# The renderer is not using the texture in Open TK

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, opentk, texture2d

Hi I'm trying to use Textures in OpenGL using Open TK. I got a basic example from the [official page of OpenTK Framework](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/textures), but didn't work. I searched here on stackoverflow for some help and changed some parts of the code, but still is not working. (Found and tested: [OpenTk texture not display the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169452/opentk-texture-not-display-the-image))

So far I came with this snippet, but this is not displaying the texture (display white instead):

**UPDATED** (With @The Fiddler suggestions)

In `OpenTK.GLControl.Load` event handler:

```
GL.ClearColor(Color.MidnightBlue);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

GL.Viewport(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(0, 4, 0, 3, -1, 1);

GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

GL.GenTextures(1, out textureId);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

var bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\myfolder\texture.png");
var data = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + GL.GetError());

bmp.UnlockBits(data);
```

In `OpenTK.GLControl.Paint` event handler:

```
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId);

GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);

GL.TexCoord2(0, 0); GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
GL.TexCoord2(0, 1); GL.Vertex2(0, 1);
GL.TexCoord2(1, 1); GL.Vertex2(1, 1);
GL.TexCoord2(1, 0); GL.Vertex2(1, 0);

GL.End();

control.SwapBuffers();
```

The erro code get in first part is: `1281` = `ErrorCode.InvalidValue`.
Does anyone have any idea why it isn't rendering the texture?

Comment: You need to find which line is causing the InvalidValue error. Either add more calls to `GL.GetError()` or compile a debug version of OpenTK.dll and use that (the debug version will throw an exception whenever an OpenGL error occurs.)

Answer (score 0):

A white texture typically means (a) an incomplete texture definition or (b) an OpenGL error state messing up with your rendering. Your texture definitions looks correct, so try calling `GL.GetError()` to check if any OpenGL errors crop up.

Note that `PixelInternalFormat.Rgb8` requires OpenGL 3.x, so you need to check if OpenGL 3.x is supported before using that. Alternatively, try using `PixelInternalFormat.Rgb` or `PixelInternalFormat.Rgba` which are supported all the way back to OpenGL 1.1.

Edit: you can find a complete working example at ["Texture.cs"](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/Source/Examples/OpenGL/1.x/Textures.cs). You can run this through the example browser in your OpenTK installation (OpenGL -> 1.x -> Textures).

Comment: I'm add a update with `GL.GetError()`. And also change the parameters of image. Please check it out.